# Flutter web- ımage uploaded storage but didnt upload firebase cloud

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, storage

Error: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.

I got this error when I added new image to firebase
all of my codes here  if anyone knows how to solve this issue

I tried a lot of ways but coudnt solve problem
Error: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.

I got this error when I added new image to firebase
all of my codes here  if anyone knows how to solve this issue

I tried a lot of ways but coudnt solve problem

```
Future <String> uploadBannerImageToDb (url )async {
    String downloadUrl= await storage.ref(url).getDownloadURL();
    if(downloadUrl!=null){
      firestore.collection('slider').add({
        'image' : downloadUrl,
      });
    }
    return downloadUrl;
  }
 

void uploadImage({ @required Function(File file)onSelected}){
    InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement()..accept='image/*';
    uploadInput.click();
    uploadInput.onChange.listen((event){
      final file = uploadInput.files.first;
      final reader = FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
        onSelected(file);
      });
    });
  }

  
  void uploadStorage(){
    
    final dateTime = DateTime.now();
    final path = 'bannerImage/$dateTime';
    uploadImage(onSelected: (file){
      if(file!=null){
        setState(() {
          _fileNameTextController.text=file.name;
          _imageSelected=false;
          _url=path;
        });
        fb.storage().refFromURL('gs://groceryapp-fcb53.appspot.com').child(path).put(file);
      }
    });

  }

Visibility(
                        visible: _visible,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              AbsorbPointer(
                                absorbing:true,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 300, height: 30,
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: _fileNameTextController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.black45,width: 1,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                                        hintText: 'Uploaded Image',
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                              ),
                              FlatButton(onPressed: (){
                                uploadStorage();
                              },
                                child: Text('Upload Image',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),color: Colors.black45,),
                              SizedBox(width: 10,),
                              AbsorbPointer(
                                absorbing: _imageSelected,
                                child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
                                  progressDialog.show();
                                  _services.uploadBannerImageToDb(_url).then((downloadUrl){
                                    if(downloadUrl!=null){
                                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                                      _services.showMyDialog(
                                        title: 'New Banner Image',
                                        message: 'Saved Banner Image Succesfully',
                                        context: context,
                                      );
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                                    child: Text('Save Image',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                                  color: _imageSelected ? Colors.grey : Colors.black45,
                                ),
                              ),
```

Comment: what version of FirebaseStorage are you using?

Comment: firebase_core: "^1.0.2"
  cloud_firestore: "^1.0.3"
  firebase_auth: "^1.0.1"
  firebase: ^9.0.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should use `child(path).putfile(file);` instead of `put(file)`. And await for it, then call getdownloadurl.

Comment: thank you but its not working  'child(path).putfile(file);' when ı wrote underline the code I uploaded storage but I didnt upload cloud my rules allow read and write with timestamp  I dont know where is the problem

Comment: Use await before `fb.storage().refFromURL`

Comment: I tried ur solution its not working I tired another app my codes worked but in this app its not working, a little bit confusing

Comment: I tracked codes with break points Error occurs in the upload  <pre> Future <String> uploadBannerImageToDb (url )async {
    String downloadUrl= await storage.ref(url).getDownloadURL();<code> giving a object to object not found error  I defined  for cloud db   <pre> CollectionReference banners = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("slider");<code>   and second error is here  fb.storage().refFromURL('gs://groceryapp-fcb53.appspot.com').child(path).put(file);<code> " Error R " I tried a lot of way but not solve the problem  I dont upload cloud yet I uploaded storage with this code not cloud

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and its working maybe someone will need

```
    _services.uploadBannerImageToDb('<yourstoragelink>/$_url').then((downloadUrl){
                                if(downloadUrl!=null){
                                  progressDialog.dismiss();
                                  _services.showMyDialog(
                                    title: 'New Banner Image',
                                    message: 'Saved Banner Image Succesfully',
                                    context: context,
                                  );
                                }
                              });
```